# Batch scan and delete

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I need a batchscript, that will scan all the files in the original folder and then the files in the destination folder.
After files are scanned, I want the script to delete the files/folders found in the destination folder but not in the original folder (Sync two folders).

[image: WHAT I EXACTLY NEED]

---

MY CODE NOW:

```
XCOPY \school\* z:\school /D /S /E /R /Y /C >> D:\Logs\log.TXT
```

Comment: Which Operating System ?

Comment: Take a look at Powershell and [Get-ChildItem](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh849800.aspx)

Comment: [`robocopy` command with `/PURGE` switch](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)?

Comment: @JosefZ XCOPY \school\* z:\school /D /S /E /R /Y /C >> D:\Logs\log.TXT This is my code now. What I need is a script that will delete the files in \school\ when they were deleted in z:\school

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /S /A z:\school\*') do echo %%~pG` for the first look;  improved to `… do if not exist "%%~pG" echo del "%%~G"` could become your starting point...

Comment: @JosefZ First I'm going to find out, what it means (the script) than I will edit it for my purpose. Thanks!